# Как запушить елемент в массив через замыкание?

Tags: javascript, массивы, замыкания, push

Как можно запушить в массив элементы при помощи замыкания? 
Естественно выдает **undefined**.

Камнями не кидайте , я только учусь.

```
function storeAge() {

    let store = [];
    return function addName(names) {
        store.push(names)
    }
}

const name4 = storeAge('ddd');
name4()
```

Comment: А возвращать данные вы планируете?

Comment: нет , нужно просто заполнить массив

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получаем функцию в **name4** а уже при вызове **name4** передаем значение, которое нужно запушить в массив

```js
function storeAge() {
    const store = [];
    return function addName(names) {
        store.push(names);
        return store;
    }
}

const name4 = storeAge();
console.log(name4(1))
console.log(name4(2))
console.log(name4(3))
```

Comment: В примере добавлен return для демонстрации, что все работает, как надо!

Comment: получилось , спасибо